# How to get text from EditText in Config Layout Android?

Tags: java, android, configuration

I have config layout contains `EditText` is `serverString` when user input.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/serverURL"
    android:inputType="textUri"
    android:hint="@string/server_url_hint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="20" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

And code to class `Configuration_Activity.java` to get values. This is my code:

```
private void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    serverUrl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.serverURL);
}
```

But I don't know how to get values when user input and user press button back, text will saved, and this code like:

```
serverUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
});
```

In other class I want to get values of `EditText` to process, this class `extends from Services`, I can't using `findViewById` to get values. This is my code:

```
public class Zing extends Service {
    final String serverUrlString = "http://www.myserver.com";
}
```

In this code, the variable `serverUrlString` is not flexible. So I want to when user input text in Configuration this will save then `serverUrlSTring` get this text to continues process.

UPDATED:

Send to @Eduardo Yáñez Parareda:

I tried your updated code. It has much different in my application.
First, I try your code it can't find `IBinder`, `bindService`, I try change to like:

serverUrl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Context c = getApplicationContext();
    final String serverStringURL = serverUrl.getText().toString();
    preferenceManager.setServerUrlText(serverStringURL);
    Intent serverStartIntent = new Intent(c, CallRecordService.class);
    serverStartIntent.putExtra("serverStringURL",serverStringURL.toString());
    startActivity(serverStartIntent);
}
});
```

But in `class Zing extends Services` I can't getExtra(values). Because this class extends Services.

Thanks.

Comment: IBinder is in API 23: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/IBinder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start your service with an Intent and send extra values, override the method onStart, then get the intent and related information:

// Or you can extend from IntentService (API 23)

```
public class Zing extends Service {
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // It'd be better call another method passing the Intent...
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know. I want this autosave. But how to get this values in class `Zing.java` extends Services.

Comment: My previous answer was based on API 23, but I've updated it again

Comment: What is `START_STICKY` mean? In `onStartCommand` I created thread and this `return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);`

Comment: Please, read reference docs about Android services: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/services.html http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 serverUrl.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String ServerStr = s.toString();
        }
    });
```